# How to implement and modify's newton's method on MATLAB/OCTAVE?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement Newton's method. Iterative method of order 2. and adapt it to calculate the not-null solution of an ecuation (x=1-e^(-2x) with 4 exact decimals.

I cant figure out how the output should look. I've tried to implement the method for finding better approximations to the zero with initial aproximation

```
function [x , res , xvec , resvec] = newton( f, df, x0, maxiter, tol )

function x(k) = newton( f, df, x0, maxiter, tol )
k(1:maxiter)
f = @x(k)
df = @(x(k))'
x(k)= x0-(f(x0)/df(x0))
x(k+1) = x(k) - (f(x(k))/df(x(k)))
end
while (iter < maxiter)
  while (abs(f(n)-(f(n-1)) > tol)
    x(1)= x0-(f(x0)/df(x0))
  elseif (iter > maxiter) 
    error('maximum amount of iterations exceeded')
  end
end
fprintf('step(k)      x(k)       |f(xk)|     |x(k+1)-x(k)|')
fprintf('------    -----------  ---------    -------------\n')
fprintf('%d %d %.4f %.4f\n', k, x(k), mod(f(xk)), mod(x(k+1)−x(k)) )
```

I expected to show me the result with qpproximation to 4 deciamls

Comment: Stop adding tags for languages that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and remove the tag which your language isn't (i.e. leave only MATLAB or Octave, they are different languages)

Comment: I am trying to modify the newton's method so that the result of that equation its a not-null solution with approximation of 4 decimals. the result should be something like: 1.4444

Comment: OK, add a [mcve] to run your code.

Comment: That code has too many syntax errors. If you really are using MATLAB, you will find the editor’s built-in linter giving you many errors and warnings. Try to fix those before posting here, I don’t see why you would ask people to do something for you that your computer can do. Once your code makes sense, include in your question a clear description of the problem you are facing. Error message? Wrong output? See [ask].